# DataDirectory macro works for SQL Server CE 3.5, but not 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-ce, connection-string

In attempting to upgrade a WinForms application using SQL CE 3.5 to 4.0, I found that the DataDirectory macro was not getting replaced. SqlCeConnection.DataSource always shows "|DataDirectory|" instead of the actual path after changing the project reference to point to the CE 4.0 library. All other code was the same. To rule out any other problems, I tested again after removing CE 3.5 (though MSDN says they can be installed side by side), but with no success.

I created the sample WinForms app below and I get the same results: if I simply change the library reference to 3.5, it works as expected; if I use 4.0, it does not.

For what it's worth, I forced the platform target to both x86 and x64 with the same results for each CE version/platform combination.

Any ideas?

Here's the simple Windows Form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Sql4Test.sdf";

    private void btnSetDataDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataDirectory = @"C:\Projects";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirectory);
        lblDataDirectory.Text = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string;
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            lblDataSource.Text = conn.DataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A part from the output obtained. If you try to open the connection? Works or not? If not, what is the error message?

Comment: It works perfectly. I added a simple method to the test form to create a table using 4.0, and it did with no problems. [Edit] I should add... I had not tried that previously because my original code had a System.IO.File.Exists check which failed due to the macro not getting replaced. So... I guess the problem is actually solved, and I'll just have to change that particular File.Exists check.

Comment: Well, this article seems to explain your case http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f132e2a0-0f58-4685-9663-f72a7857fa52/40-sqlceconnectiondatabase-bug-or-feature?forum=sqlce  and offers also a workaround. [ErikEJ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) is a frequent user here and author of the **Sql Server Compact Toolbox**

Comment: Very helpful, Steve, thanks. I'm familiar with Erik's site and use his Toolbox daily. I should have checked there!